# jQuery Mobile issue with panels and swipe

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe

I am having a weird problem happening with Android devices only. Basically I want the panel to open as it should while clicking the designated button. It seems to work fine on all devices except for Android on Galaxy s2 and Galaxy nexus 2 (only Androids I have tested on).

This is what happens when you swipe to the left on Android:
[image: Android Swipe]

I cannot for the life of me figure out why its doing it. You can see it in action [here](http://www.albertoandco.com/mobile/test.html).

To reiterate I *don't* want anything to happen when the user swipes left/right.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

**Edit:** I tried adding the following to no avail:

```
$('div').on('swipeleft', function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Comment: Side note: you need to movie `/images/` directly under JQM js file. Icons are not appearing in your website.

Comment: Icons are not appearing because I need to update the theme icons to 1.3.1 -- not too worried about that right now. I need to get this swipe issue fixed.

Comment: Have you tried `stopImmediatePropagation()` on swipe left? Regarding my previous comment, CSS not JS, sorry :)

Comment: Hey that works! Could you please add it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Actually I spoke too soon. It's still doing it.

Comment: Hahaha..it's okay. Can you post what you've added?